# Difference between varchar and nvarchar in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Please ecplain the usuability difference between varchar and nvarchar in MYSQL

In which case, we should use varchar datatype column and nvarchar datatype column using MySQL

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-national.html

Comment: As a general rule "National Char" was a solution to store characters outside the ASCII range in the old days when Unicode didn't exist or wasn't yet implemented. Depending on the engine a national char can have several drawbacks, and nowadays it's cleaner and much simpler to stick to Unicode VARCHAR columns if you need non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @shadow Unfortunate choice of question as the dupe as the accepted answer is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

Nvarchar and Varchar both are used to store variable length character data type.
But Nvarchar stores unicode characters like chinese,japanese.
Nvarchar length is two times its actual length.